# How can I remove the title bar in Tkinter on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, titlebar

Is it possible to remove the title bar in Tkinter python without removing the close, minimise, and fullscreen buttons on a Mac? I have been unable to find anything useful.

Comment: but... close, minimise, and fullscreen buttons are **on the titlebar**, how do you expect that to look like? if you want to remove the title bar you will need to create your own buttons or menu to preserve the functionality of close, minimise, and fullscreen. You will also need to handle that the window won't be shown in the taskbar

Comment: *remove the title bar in Tkinter* - maybe ```<tk. Tk>.title('')```

Comment: remove the title bar? Did you want to remove this [platform-specific menu](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#platformmenus)?